# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at RECOVER_fyp1_fla::MainTimeline/abc1()

Tags: actionscript-3

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at RECOVER_fyp1_fla::MainTimeline/abc1()`

Hi, what does this mean? Can anybody figure it out? Thanks.

Code:

```
swatter.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,abc1);

Mouse.hide();



function abc1(e:Event)
{
    swatter.x = mouseX;
    swatter.y = mouseY;

    enter code here

    mosq1.y = mosq1.y + 2;
    mosq2.y = mosq2.y + 3;
    mosq3.y = mosq3.y + 4;
    mosq4.y = mosq4.y + 5;
    mosq5.y = mosq5.y + 6;



    if (mosq1.y > 640)
    {
        mosq1.y = -50;
    }

    if (mosq2.y > 640)
    {
        mosq2.y = -50;
    }

    if (mosq3.y > 640)
    {
        mosq3.y = -50;
    }

    if (mosq4.y > 640)
    {
        mosq4.y = -50;
    }

    if (mosq5.y > 640)
    {
        mosq5.y = -50;
    }


    if(swatter.hitTestObject(mosq1))
    {
        //SoundMixer.stopAll();
        //three_start_sound1.play();
        mosq1.parent.removeChild(mosq1);
    }

    if(swatter.hitTestObject(mosq2))
    {
        //SoundMixer.stopAll();
        //three_start_sound1.play();
        mosq2.parent.removeChild(mosq2);
    }

    if(swatter.hitTestObject(mosq3))
    {
        //SoundMixer.stopAll();
        //three_start_sound1.play();
        mosq3.parent.removeChild(mosq3);
    }

    if(swatter.hitTestObject(mosq4))
    {
        //SoundMixer.stopAll();
        //three_start_sound1.play();
        mosq4.parent.removeChild(mosq4);
    }

    if(swatter.hitTestObject(mosq5))
    {
        //SoundMixer.stopAll();
        //three_start_sound1.play();
        mosq5.parent.removeChild(mosq5);
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Go to your the Flash IDE's "Publish Settings" and toggle "Permit Debugging".  You may want to also compile in debug mode using control-shift-enter, which will jump directly to the line of code that's having issues, and show you a call stack, as well as the current state of all variables.  That said, you have two entries of `enter code here` which should at least be commented out.  Also, you're addressing mosq1-5's `y` property, yet you're removing the object at some point, which means concurrent clicks will throw the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

but these variables:

```
mosq1.y = mosq1.y + 2;
mosq2.y = mosq2.y + 3;
mosq3.y = mosq3.y + 4;
mosq4.y = mosq4.y + 5;
mosq5.y = mosq5.y + 6;
```

are instantiated?? Peraphs these are null.

Error code is clear, you're trying to use a property of a NULL object